# Sequential criterion: "... Every sequences $x_n$ in $D$ converging to $c$ ..."

Tags: real-analysis, limits

The sequential criterion for the existence of limits states that,

> Let $D\subset \mathbb{R}$ and $f:D\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function. Let $c$ be a limit point of $D$ and $l\in \mathbb{R}$. Then $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow c} f(x)=l$ if and only if for *every* sequence $(x_n)$ in $D-\{c\}$ converging to $c$, the sequence $(f(x_n))$ convergs to $l$.

What I want to know is in this part,

$$\textbf{every sequence $(x_n)$ in $D-\{c\}$ converging to $c$}$$

what does it mean for "every" sequence $(x_n)$ to have the same range $\left( D-\{c\}\right)$ and the same limit $(c)$, because in that case wouldn't the sequences become the same?

Comment: I'm not quite sure where is the problem, we are simply restricting the sequences to be those which satisfies the criterion.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is appropriate to give an example.

Let $f \colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be given by

$$x \mapsto \begin{cases} 0, & \text{ if } x \geq 0 \\ 1, &\text{ if } x < 0\end{cases}.$$

What is $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)$? Does it even exist (i.e., does it have a value)?

Well, take the sequence $(x_n)$ given by $x_n = \frac1n$, which converges to $0$, the limit point we are looking at. Then $f(x_n) = 0$ for every $n$, and so $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) = 0$.

However, if you take the sequence $(y_n)$ given by $y_n = - \frac1n$, then again $(y_n)$ converges to $0$, but $f(y_n) = 1$ for every $n$. Hence $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(y_n) = 1$.

Here you see that $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(z_n)$ depends on the choice of the sequence $(z_n)$, which converges to $0$.

What follows is that $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)$ does not exist.